# Asp.Net MVC 5 reflect role changes immediately

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, role-based-access-control

In Asp.Net MVC, if a user's role is changed while he is already logged in, it won't be actually reflected until the user logs out and logs back in.

Is there any way to make role changes reflect immediately? I'm using the default Asp.Net identity.